# Умножение матрицы на поинт

Tags: c++, opencv

Имеется матрица (допустим `3x3`) которая применяется для преобразования некоего массива двумерных точек (допустим `std::vector<Point>`). Как это грамотно сделать средствами `opencv`? Нашел вариант с перемножением матриц через `operator*` (для этого преобразуем `vector` в `Map`), но при попытке преобразовать результат к `cv::Mat` получаю ошибку:

```
put_asset: /home/levkovitch/Public/tmp/put_assets/main.cpp:119: cv::Rect operator*(const cv::Mat&, const Rect&): Assertion `matrix.elemSize() == 3' failed.
```

PSS вообще массив точек - это вершины прямоугольника `cv::Rect`

Comment: [mcve]? что-то не вижу `operator*` в доках...

Comment: @Fat-Zer странно, но в доках я почему-то тоже не могу ее найти, хотя она есть. В файле `core/mat.hpp`:3583 (для версии 4.1). А по поводу минимально-воспроизводимого примера - так его нет, вопрос не в том, почему выбивает ошибку (зря я наверно это добавил, вызывает путаницу), а как это сделать правильно. Просто указал, что этот способ не подходит

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cv::perspectiveTransform` принимает вектор точек и матрицу

Comment: то что нужно. Спасибо